# How to link a cname to the IP to access spring boot apis deployed on {IPADDRESS}:8080 on AWS EC2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-ec2

I have a spring boot application and is deployed in aws ec2 instance. I can access the api's using http://{public_ip_address}:8080/ContextName/api, however I want to access it with a **cname** like **http://api.myapp.io/ContextName/api**

Can anyone suggest anything?

Answer (score 0):

A CNAME allows you to map one domain name to another. You could map `api.myapp.io` to `something.example.com`. The CNAME only affects the domain name and not the port, though.

What makes the port "disappear" in your second example is that it infers the standard port of the `http://` protocol, which is 80. Any port other than 80 that should be accessed using HTTP has to be specified using the `:<portNumber>` after the domain name.

If you want to point a domain name to your EC2 instance, you should use an A-Record, which maps a domain name to an IPv4 address. You should be aware that your Public IP address will most likely change after a reboot, so you should consider using an Elastic-IP.

The port number is a bit more difficult. You either start your app on port 80, or you employ some sort of reverse-proxy like HA-Proxy or nginx on your server that forwards traffic from port 80 to port 8080 of your App.